# Library/Framework for Single Page Application Development (as of 2013)

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, single-page-application

In my company we've built a few in-house mobile web apps based on **jQuery Mobile**. Now we're transitioning to more serious stuff, and JQM has been ruled out because it is too slow. (We did our best trying to configure it, but in the end it was all in vain. Even in quad core mobile devices it takes 1s. to process a button click).

However I loved the way it loaded pseudo-pages using ajax. Since we have many developers familiar with JQM's Single Page approach, I'm now searching for **a replacement working in a similar fashion**. I'd like to know if as of now (2013) there exists a library or framework meeting most of the following requirements:

- It swaps in and out the html of each "page" into the main one.
- It provides at least one lifecycle-related event (e.g.: onPageLoad, onPageShown, onPageHidden, etc)
- Single html file for each "pseudopage".
- Fully Javascript based.

Bonus points. It would be nice if:

- It provided a standard way of passing parameters to the "page" controller or initialization callback, or some built-in mechanism to help with initialization or recreating state. (I don't want each dev doing this in a different manner).
- It handled the back navigation, maybe allowing parameters back to the previous "page" as well.
- It allowed to choose whether to recreate the "page" each time it is shown, or show it in the last state.

However I don't really need:

- Mandatory complex MV* stuff. We'll be using an `ORM` and there'll be `DAOs` but we don't want to be forced to code adapters to adhere to the framework's idea of what the model is.
- Updates to the view when the model changes.
- Templates (the views should be `HTML5` and no preprocessor tool should be needed).
- Built-in widgets (The design guys had enough with `jQuery Mobile` and they'll be using something different, probably Bootstrap).

(However I don't mind if it had any of these as long as they are optional to use)

I think it would not be very difficult to do it myself, but I'd like to hear your suggestions before reinventing the wheel. [PagesJS](http://pagesjs.chrisdlangton.com/#!home) looks like a good candidate by the moment.

Comment: re: 1 second button clicks: half of that wait is the phone on a blank page, did you try fastclick?

Comment: 250-300 ms delay by phone on click, tap...etc

Comment: @dandavis The fastclick plugin? It defaults to vclick on non iOS devices. Plus we are already using "tap" instead when we are on touch enabled devices. So it's not only the 300ms issue, its also showing/hidding dialogs, heavy DOM manipulation, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made my own jQuery plugin. It manages the page-swapping and the ajax loading from files, firing custom events before and after each page is shown. Took no more than 150 lines comments included. I kept the parameter-passing stuff out, though.